Auto-update for sideloaded app - PackageManager not recognized
I'm trying to follow the instructions here to add auto-update capability to a non-store app packaged with a Windows Application Packaging project:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/non-store-developer-updates
I've added this section to the Package.appxmanifest file:
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="packageManagement" />
  </Capabilities>

When I get to the part where it instructs how to apply the update (for packages deployed without an app installer file), the following statement doesn't compile:
PackageManager packagemanager = new PackageManager();

'PackageManager' is not recognized. I think this is in the 'Windows.Management.Deployment' namespace, but that namespace isn't recognized in my Avalonia .NET 8 application.
Is this from a nuget package?

Please, no AI drivel - I've already gone through what ChatGPT has to say about this.
